# Parse.com Cloud Code: Fast Way of Creating Pointers than Object Queries/Manual

Tags: javascript, rest, pointers, express, parse-platform

Is there a way to create a pointer by objectId?  Manually creating pointers and full database queries seems a bit tedious.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the Vote afterSave code and describe what you want it to do.

Comment: Updated to include code

Comment: Please post the whole afterSave method and please describe the relevant column names/types.  As a guess before seeing this, I can tell you that a lot of folks make the mistake of creating string columns containing object ids, rather than pointer columns containing objects.  Also, need more context on what you pasted, but for sure `request.user_id` is wrong, the other way `request.object.get("user_id")` might be right but need to see more context per the above.

Comment: Updated with the info you wanted. Thanks for the help Dan

Comment: Edited + Got it working!  The user pointer was pointed to Relational which isn't even something I have as a class.  Don't know how that happened.  Thanks Dan!  Still, is there a faster way to create pointers than manually or querying whole objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the edited question to be about how to create pointers, here's a general purpose function:

```
// return a pointer to an object with a given id and given class
function pointerTo(objectId, klass) {
    return { __type:"Pointer", className:klass, objectId:objectId };
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll use this.